# How to search for multiple keywords in a textfile in Python

Tags: python, text

Lets say keywords1.txt contains the following:

```
Broken Screen
```

Then I write this program:

```
sentence = input("Input your sentence: ")
if open('keywords1.txt').read() in sentence:
    print("hello there")
```

I wanted it to display 'hello there' whenever i say for example:
my screen is broken

But it doesn't work.
Putting those wods in a textfile as a list still doesn't work:

```
Broken
Screen
```

Comment: Case sensitive?  Broken vs broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic algorithm for that. Maybe there is some function in python to make it easy, but this is the most basic code.

```
sentence = input("Input your sentence: ")
findCount = 0
lines = 0
fLines = open('keywords1.txt').readlines()
for line in fLines:
    lines += 1
    if line in sentence:
       findCount += 1
if lines == findCount:
   print("hello there")
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I needed this for my controlled assessment gcse! You helped me out a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Check re module

Maybe a re.match or re.find

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `set` method `issubset` to do that:

```
sentence = input("Input your sentence: ")
A = open('keywords1.txt').read().split('\n') # or any other separator
B = sentence.split()
A, B = set(A), set(B)  

if A.issubset(B) :
    print("hello there")
```